# What is the meaning of あいつはあいつで?

Tags: expressions

I encountered the phrase in this line:

> あいつはあいつで、きちんとバイトしているらしい。

I think I can intuit the general meaning but I was wondering if anyone had a full explanation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

「あいつはあいつで～～」 means "He ~~ in his own way."

As the word 「きちんと = "properly"」 may suggest,

> **"Pronoun X + は + Same Pronoun X + で"**

expresses the speaker's opinion that the Person X is doing something at least on a satisfactory level if not on an extraordinary level.

「これはこれでおいしい。」 = "This dish tastes OK if not spectacular." ==> "It tastes good in its own way."

One can also use a real personal name instead of a pronoun in this expression as in.

> 「スミスはスミスでちゃんと働{はたら}いている。」

Comment: Is "if not perfect" required? For example, "Aさんも面白いが、BさんはBさんで面白い" just means Bさん is also funny in his own way which is different from Aさん. This does not imply Bさん is only satisfactory, nor does it say which person is relatively better.

Comment: OP's sentence talks only about one person and yours talks about two.  That is the difference.