# What does the pattern [xはxで] mean?

Tags: clause-pattern

It appears like this, in a sentence about surfing:
前のめりにすると、前は前で浮力が無くなります。
I know the general meaning is "If you lean over forward, ...the flotation goes away."
I think that the meaning of "前は前で" is something like, "the front (of the board) being what it is..." (i.e., The nose of the board is very thin, so it has very little flotation.)
But I'm not sure if that's correct.  Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30134/7810

Answer (score 14):

> 「Noun + **は** + Same Noun + **で** + ～～」

is a common expression used to describe, somewhat emphatically, a unique characteristic or state of the thing being talked about.

Thus, your translation "the front (of the board) being what it is..." is very good.

I was just trying to choose between two girls by murmuring to myself:

「じゅん子{こ}**は**じゅん子**で**かわいいし、ナオミ**は**ナオミ**で**おもしろいからなあ・・　どっちにしよう？」

= "Junko sure is pretty and Naomi is really funny.  Who should I pick?"