# How shall I understand this sentence (from こころ by 夏目漱石)?

Tags: meaning, translation

I came along this sentence in the very begining of the story :

「友達は中国のある資産家の息子で金に不自由のない男であったけれども、*学校が学校なのと年が年なので*、生活の程度は私とそう変わりもしなかった。」

Here's the translation I read : "My friend was from a wealthy family in the Central Provinces, and had no financial worries. But being a young student, his standard of living was much the same as my own. I was therefore not obliged, when I found myself alone, to change my lodgings."

Basically, I roughly understand what corresponds to what between the sentence and the translation, but I feel like 学校が学校なのと年が年なので is more of an expression, something that you can't really translate in english. Thus, I don't really get the meaning of this sentence, probably because of なの. 
I think the part of the translation that correspond to it would be : "But being a young student, his standard of living was much the same as my own."

How does this sentence work and how did they come to translate it the way they did ?

Comment: Dupe?: [What does 「学校が学校」, 「年が年」and such mean exactly?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42663/5010)