# A は A、 B は B Please help in parsing this sentence 「油ものは油もの、茶飲み茶碗は茶飲み茶碗と」

Tags: particles, syntax

This is from Hayashi Fumiko's writing titled 生活 describing the author's daily life in 1935.

> 夕御飯が済んで、小さい女中と二人で、油ものは油もの、茶飲み茶碗は茶飲み茶碗と、あれこれと近所の活動写真の話などをしながらかたづけものをして、剪花(きりばな)に水を替えてやっていると、もうその頃はたいてい八時が過ぎている。

The part that I don't get is [油ものは油もの、茶飲み茶碗は茶飲み茶碗と] and how does it relate to the rest of the sentence.

How can I look up this grammar point?

Comment: Kinda related?: [What does 「学校が学校」, 「年が年」and such mean exactly?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42663/)

Comment: ^ それは関係ないです (^^;)

Answer (score 5):

油ものは油もの、茶飲み茶碗は茶飲み茶碗と continues to かたづけものをして.

This describes washing the dishes, separating 「油もの」 and 「茶飲み茶碗」.

It's like... 油ものは油もの、茶飲み茶碗は茶飲み茶碗、と(いうふうに)**分けて・別々に**洗う・片付ける.

（「茶飲み茶碗」は水洗いでいいですが、「油もの」は石けんか洗剤のようなものがないと洗えないので）

Comment: I thought 油もの meant "foods cooked in oil," and that's what my dictionary says, too. But here it seems to mean "dishes that are oily" or maybe "dishes that were used for oily foods." (That's "dishes" as in "plates, bowls, etc.") Is this a common usage?

Comment: そうですね、うちでは普通に、油っ気のある物に使った食器類や調理器具を洗うとき、「[油]{あぶら}もの」って言ったりしますね。ググっても結構使われてます　https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22%E6%B2%B9%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%82%92%E6%B4%97%E3%81%86%22%E3%80%80&bih=568&biw=1242&hl=ja&sxsrf=APq-WBuNgenKdzZPG5aKW_R95iUdQT4YQQ%3A1646179823711&ei=77UeYvOAK4uD1e8PpKme6Ac&ved=0ahUKEwiztIPdkab2AhWLQfUHHaSUB30Q4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=%22%E6%B2%B9%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%82%92%E6%B4%97%E3%81%86%22%E3%80%80&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQgAEKIEMgUIABCiBDIFCAAQogQyBQgAEKIEMgUIABCiBDoHCAAQRxCwA0oECEEYAEoECEYYAFDCB1ivKmDILWgBcAF4AIABrQSIAZoTkgELMC40LjEuMS4yLjGYAQCgAQHIAQXAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that; even with google, I'm not very good at figuring out if a given usage is common or "correct." (And one thing I've learned from this site is that even good dictionaries seem to be a bit less complete and/or up to date than I would have expected.)