# What does nameはnameで mean?

Tags: particle-で, nouns

> 井上は井上で待つだけじゃなく。自分から彼に話しかければいいじゃないか

I understand he's basically "You shouldn't just wait. Approach him on your own"

But what does the repeated noun here adds?

Comment: @Chocolate why didn't you consider the question a duplicate, eventually?

Comment: Also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/78118/5010 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30134/5010 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41752/5010 I don't think "typicalness" is relevant in this pattern.

Comment: @jarmanso7 Because I was hoping someone would post an answer mentioning the nuance of `problem` or `criticism`, and Naruto-san did! [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/101840/9831) (＾＾)／

Answer (score 3):

> **井上は井上で**、待つだけじゃなく自分から彼に話しかければいいじゃないか
>
> - **Inoue, for your part**, you should talk to him instead of just waiting around.
> - **Inoue, you have your own problem!** Don't just wait, why don't you approach him on your own?

This `AはAで` is an important construction that basically means "in A's own way". Here it's used to indicate that Inoue has **his own** problem (although the other person has a problem). You haven't provided any previous context, but a sentence like this never appears without context. There should be a criticism of **someone else** just before this, for example, something like "佐藤はもっと周囲に気を配り、仲間はずれの人がいないか気をつけるべきだ".

See the following questions for similar examples.

- [Meaning of あいつはあいつで](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/78118/5010)

  > It's used when the process/reason/method is different but the essential result/conclusion is the same.
- [What is the meaning of あいつはあいつで?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21167/5010)
- [Meaning of 「これはこれで」, and the difference between it and 「それはそれとして」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30134/5010)
- [What does the pattern [xはxで] mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41752/5010)

And [the answer to this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72280/5010) lists several patterns that look similar.

Answer (score 2):

In the case where N is animate noun, followed by a verb referring to behaviour, the meaning of NはNで is '(that is) just like N', 'N, typically enough':

文子は文子でなにも手伝ってくれなかった 'That's Fumiko for you, not a bit of help.'

指揮者は指揮者で給料もらわなきゃ食えないしね "For his part, the conductor has to get a salary or he can't eat, you see."

井上は井上で待つだけじゃなくて would normally mean 'Inoue, being Inoue, not only does he wait, [but]...'; is there some error in the text quoted?

Comment: Yes, it's く　not くて so I guess it's adverbial here. "Don't wait like you usually" kind of nuance?

Comment: The absence of て doesn't change the meaning; normally 'Aだけじゃなく（て）', means 'not only A, but' (where 'A' could be a noun or a sentence), and in this case the subject of 待つ is 井上, thus 'not only does Inoue wait, but...'. A little more context might make it clear.

Comment: @N.Hunt do you know by any chance where I can find a more formal explanation of this grammar pattern or just more info on it? I'm interested to know more, but of course googling "は で grammar" just brings lots of unrelated information regarding only は or で...

Comment: Yes, an internet search doesn't turn up anything really useful. The only place I've ever seen this construction explained is in Samuel Martin, A Reference Grammar of Japanese, and that's more or less what I have written above. I don't have at hand the Japan Times 'Dictionary of Japanese Grammar', but it might touch on this usage. This construction is basically NはN でも, with も omitted as it commonly is. For example, それはそれでよかった, 'That was alright as it was (or as far as it went)'.

Comment: Just found [this](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AF%E2%80%A6%E3%81%A7/) which seems to describe it.

Comment: @N.Hunt I don't see how to derive the meaning from NはN で**も**, but the link you provided is very helpful and the example sentence definitely easy to remember too: 夏は夏で暑いし、冬は冬で寒い. Thanks!

Comment: 井上 doesn't normally chases people but waits for them to come I believe

Comment: Ah, then that makes sense.