# meaning of あれはあれで

Tags: grammar

かつてを振り返って、僕は思う。**あれはあれで**輝かしい時代だったのかもしれない、と。

what does this mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/21168/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30134/9831