# What does the expression "こっちはこっちで" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I have a quick question about something I've come across in a piece of Japanese fiction:

> こっちはこっちで結構やばい橋を渡ってたんだぜ？

The "こっちはこっちで" I believe is an expression but it's difficult to decipher, can someone explain its meaning/how it's used?

Comment: Related or duplicate? : https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/21168/9831

Comment: yes its duplicate